# Grafana & Loki: Error connecting to datasource: Data source connected, but no labels received. Verify that Loki and Promtail is configured properly

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, grafana, grafana-loki

I am trying to ship docker logs to Loki and visualize them using Grafana. However when trying to connect to Loki from the Grafana UI I always get the following error:

```
Data source connected, but no labels received. Verify that Loki and Promtail is configured properly.
```

The first line in the code section I will provide here often is inlined, but in the files it is correct yaml.

I am not using Promtail, instead I rely on the Loki docker plugin, the section for each service in my compose.yml looks like this:

```
    logging:
  driver: loki
  options:
    loki-url: 'http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push'
```

The loki container is defined as follows:

```
loki:
hostname: loki
image: grafana/loki:2.8.3
ports:
  - "3100:3100"
command: -config.file=/etc/loki/loki-config.yaml
volumes:
  - ./volumes/loki/etc:/etc/loki
```

And this is what my Loki-config.yml looks like:

```
    auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  log_level: info

ingester:
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 5m
  chunk_retain_period: 30s
  wal:
    dir: /tmp/loki/wal

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2018-04-15
      store: boltdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v9
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 168h

storage_config:
  boltdb:
    directory: /tmp/loki/index

  filesystem:
    directory: /tmp/loki/chunks

limits_config:
  enforce_metric_name: false
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h

chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0

table_manager:
  chunk_tables_provisioning:
    inactive_read_throughput: 0
    inactive_write_throughput: 0
    provisioned_read_throughput: 0
    provisioned_write_throughput: 0
  index_tables_provisioning:
    inactive_read_throughput: 0
    inactive_write_throughput: 0
    provisioned_read_throughput: 0
    provisioned_write_throughput: 0
  retention_deletes_enabled: false
  retention_period: 0
```

Is the IP of the ingester maybe wrong. All services sit on different containers and the services producing the logs also on a different VM?

Comment: Do you have logs in Loki ? That would be the first step to be sure that your Dockers are sending their logs properly.